# How do you compare the system resources used by two programs?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google

How do you compare the system resources used by two programs (e.g., Chrome & Chrome Canary)?

I think the new 64-bit Chrome Canary is causing my computer to heat up a bit more but I'd like to compare it's system resource usage to the regular version before adopting an opinion.

Comment: in the Activity monitor

Comment: The activity monitor is showing everything and I'm not sure the browsers behavior is the same when running individually as it is simultaneously. Id like to somehow compare the two's usage statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare CPU utilisation and memory usage in Activity Monitor, in /Applications/Utilities. This lets you compare the statistics in real-time.

For a more averaged comparison, you can check the **Average Energy Impact** of an app in the Energy tab of the aforementioned app (requires ≥10.9).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Activity Monitor application, you can also use the `top -u` command in a terminal window to see the most processor-hungry applications.